What is the limit of this composed trig function (first question)?
This is my first question here so I don't know if I formatted this well. Please let me know how I could improve.
So, I was messing around on desmos, specifically with composing functions n times.
An example:
Let $ f(x) = x^2 $ and $ S_n(x) = \underbrace{(f \circ f \circ f \: ... \: \circ \: f)}_{n \: \text{times}}(x) $
Then, $ S_n(x) = x^{2^n} $
I found that if I let $f(x) = cos(x)$ , the  $ \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(x) $ is equivalent to a constant function. (see the desmos link above for a model)
I am wondering what the limit is equal to and if it can be given in a closed form. (Using either elementary or non-elementary functions)
I will check back in this forum to answer any questions

So, you will need to search for duplicates when you ask questions here.

In particular, for $\cos(x)$: Why do I get a converging result when pressing cosine multiple times on a calculator?

Going forward, with your future posted questions on MathSE, for what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number#Closed_form

Thank you everyone for the answer and feedback! I hope all you guys have a nice rest of your day!
